# How are musical beats counted?

Tags: translation, music

In English, it is common to [count beats of music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_(music)) using numbers for the beats and certain filler syllables for further subdivisions. What is the most common way to count beats in Japanese?

Adding some clarification from my comment below: For example, the bottom staff in this image shows sixteenth notes with the words "1 e & ah", and English speakers would chant "one e and ah, two e and ah..." along with the beat of the music. Is there a comparable set of syllables Japanese speakers say when counting, like "一 e and ah, 二 e and ah..."?

[image: Counting for quarter, eighth, and sixteenth notes in English]

(Image from http://www.tigerbill.com/graphics/da000814notes5.gif)

Comment: Probably it depends. But one example goes "1234, 2234, 3234, 4234"（いちにっさんしっ、にぃにっさんしっ、さんにぃさんしっ、よんにぃさんしっ）.

Comment: @user4092 Thanks, that makes sense. In your hiragana example, is there a reason why しっ is used for "4" at the end of each beat, but よん is used at the beginning of beat 4?

Comment: I think ター、ター、ター、ター for quarter notes. タン、タン 2 times for eighth notes. タカタカ 4 times for 16th notes. I think user4092’s counting beats are close to you. Mine might work for mechanical fingering exercise with metronome.

Comment: @kevinhilt You pronounce 4 as し when count is ascending probably because it's easier to utter, otherwise よん probably because it's easier to recognize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- ターアー()・タン(♩)・タ(♪)・タカ(♫) is arguably the most widely-used system for describing rhythms, and this particularly goes well with percussion instruments. I think this is basically a simplified version of "takatiki" in the article you linked.
- Japanese is mora-based, and some teachers [take advantage of the fact](https://togetter.com/li/1061625).
- いち・に・さん・し is very common for [ラジオ体操](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_calisthenics) and such where you don't have to express anything complicated. [Video](https://youtu.be/xS92XkVKM0Q).
- ワン・ツー・スリー・フォー is equally common when practicing modern dance.
- If I understand correctly, アン・ドゥ・トロワ is used by ballerinas, [チン・トン・シャン](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%83%81%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3-1369129) by *shamisen* players, and ドン・ドコ by *taiko* players.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explaining multiple systems.